# What code to use to properly display a widget (JS script) in an iframe on Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, iframe, widget, embed

I'm trying to put this code/script on our WP page using HTML block:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://stage.flyairlink.com/webcomponents/airlink-elements.js"></script>
<airlink-booking skn="”1033”"></airlink-booking>
```

On HTML preview, it looks nice:
[image]

But after publishing, it looks crap:
[image]

Should I put the widget inside an iframe? This page will be maintained by someone who doesn't know CSS or JS (like me), so the most basic code will be best.

Any other options to have it display properly?

Any help will be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Tried this one but didn't work too

<div class="sidebar-box">
    <div class="title">TEST</div>
    <div class="content">
           <script type="text/javascript" src="https://stage.flyairlink.com/webcomponents/airlink-elements.js"></script>
<airlink-booking skn="”1033”"></airlink-booking>
    </div> 
</div>

Comment: help please! :(